# I am getting error trying to close dialog (dialog.close())

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am dealing with a problem when I getting error  Property 'close' does not exist on type 'MatDialog'

My code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {LoginInfo} from '../shared/login';
import {UserService} from '../Services/user.service';
import {ModalService} from '../Services/modal/modal.service';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService, private modalService: ModalService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  closeDialog(id:string){
    this.dialog.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling open on a mat dialog you will get a MatDialogRef returned.  That is the object you want to call close on

Comment: So how should I fix this ?

Comment: Assume this is how you called `let dialogRef = dialog.open(<component>,options);` use the dialog reference to close it. `dialogRef.close()`. Refer Angular material doc for detail https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview